# "more" tag doesn't appear when browsing category achives or search

Tags: posts, tags, read-more

Almost finished my website, but ran into one problem: When you view the archive of a category or do a search, the "more" (or "continue reading") link/ tag doesn't appear. It words fine on the homepage.

Any help would be appreciated - mainly about the category post bit.

Cheers,
Will.

Comment: does the category template (category.php or archive.php) use 'the_excerpt()' or 'the_content()' ? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Comment: In the category.php file there is: get_template_part( 'loop', 'category' );

Comment: can you post the name and download link of your theme? see if your theme has a loop-category.php - if not look into loop.php and check for the 'excerpt' code. if you find 'the_excerpt()', read http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#Make_the_.22read_more.22_link_to_the_post

Comment: I'm using the bog-standard Twenty-Ten theme

Answer (score 1):

review this codex and see if the info in it can help: http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Comment: Quote: "The rest of the post continues, but when viewed on the non-single/non-permalink web page such as archives, categories, front page, and searches, the post is shown as an excerpt to the more point." Exactly what it doesn't do and I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at my 'loop.php' file like Michael said, I replaced

```
<div class="entry-summary">
            <?php the_excrept(); ?></div><!-- .entry-summary -->
```

With

```
<div class="entry-summary">
            <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div><!-- .entry-summary -->
```

Whenever it appeared (Twice, in my case)

Cheers,
Will

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the solutions I found here and on other sites didn't work for me. But I found a very simple solution, [you can read about it here](http://www.borishoekmeijer.nl/wordpress-display-the-more-tag-on-a-category-overview-page/).

```
<div class="entry">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?><em><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Link naar volledig artikel"><br/>Lees hier verder...</a></em>
    <p><small><?php the_author(); ?>, <?php the_time('j F Y') ?></small></p>
</div>
```

I used it on my category.php file, but I'm sure it works exactly the same on archive.php or search.php.